# How to load several excel files in R?

Tags: r, excel, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have about 50 excel files, all of them have the same column names. I want to combine them into a single dataframe. Here is the code I am using:

```
dir("data", full.names = T) %>% map_dfr(read_excel)
```

The excel files are stored in a folder called data. However, I am getting the following error:

Error: Can't combine `..1$Biaoti`  and `..26$Biaoti`

How can I coerce the columns to have the same type? The column Biaoti contains only 0 or 1 in all excel files.

Comment: Might be useful: https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/cell-and-column-types.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this function could help you!

```
    read_my_data <- function() {
  
  if (!require(data.table)) {install.packages("data.table")}
  
  temp <- list.files(pattern = "*.xls")
  dados <- NULL
  
  for(1 in length(temp)) {
    
    df <- fread(temp[[i]], colClasses = c(Biaoti = "factor"))
    
    dados <- rbind(dados, df)
    
  }
  
  return(dados)
  
}

read_my_data()
```

But you have to set your working directory before. This working directory must have their excel data.

This function read *.xls files, if your files are *.xlsx you have to change this function.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tydiverse)
library(readxl)


#Indicates the path of the folder where these xlsx are located
setwd('c:/.../folder')

#load files
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')

#creat the list files
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)

#makes the union of all in a dataframe
df_final<-purrr::reduce(df.list, rbind)
```